# Why are the values ​doubling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in react, and I have some issue about duplicate multiple values when I set only one. In one part of my code I have this:

the structure of my object it's some like this

```
teamRoles = [
    {
        _id: "601a9d4c74b9d4fff8a0b7bc",
        value:"Backend Engineer",
        count:0,
        talents:[
            {seniority: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
             technology: [{…}]
             _id: "r0l6o4ph0s"},
            {seniority: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
             technology: [
               _id:""602564ffcfee45ba7b96b1fe",
               options: [
                  {
                  main: false,
                  must: false,
                  name: ".Net",
                  secondary: false,
                  selected: false,
                  _id: "6024b9faef7e4646cd8c684c"
                  }
                 ]
              ],
             _id: "r0l6o4ph0s"}
           ],
        parentTech:[
            {
                _id: "6024b90fad15257ff28b9e7b",
                name: "hero",
                selected: false,
                main: false,
                secondary: false,
                must: false
            },
            {
                _id: "6024b90f7a597673a4c77001",
                name: "Nore",
                selected: false,
                main: false,
                secondary: false,
                must: false
            },
            {
                _id: "6024b90ffd5e9eeeddfaaf8f",
                name: "Mars",
                selected: false,
                main: false,
                secondary: false,
                must: false
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        _id: "601a9d4cd56bf2f049c280e5",
        value:"Business Analyst",
        count:0,
        talents:[],
        parentTech:[
            {
                _id: "6024b9faef7e4646cd8c684c",
                name: "Not",
                selected: false,
                main: false,
                secondary: false,
                must: false
            },
            {
                _id: "6024b9facd9d020fd5d82056",
                name: "Vamb",
                selected: false,
                main: false,
                secondary: false,
                must: false
            },
            {
                _id: "6024b9fab214d08c23fe4c49",
                name: "Tryo",
                selected: false,
                main: false,
                secondary: false,
                must: false
            }
        ],
    },
];
```

component grand parent

```
function LandingResults(props) {
    const roles = [...getTeamRoles()];

    return (
        <Accordion>
        <table className="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td className="">Value</td>
                <td className="w-25">Main </td>
                <td className="w-25">Value</td>
                <td className=""></td>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            {
                roles.filter((r) => r.count !== 0).length === 0 ? <tbody><tr><td colSpan="4"><p className="text-black-50">Empty...</p></td></tr></tbody>:
                roles.map((r, index)=>{

                    if (r.count>1)
                     return (
                         <tbody key={r._id}>
                             <tr>
                                <td><p><b>{r.count}</b> {r.value}</p></td>
                                <td>
                                    <DropdownMultiselectParent
                                        options={r.parentTech}
                                        idRole={r._id}
                                        counter = {r.count}
                                        nameControl = {r.value}
                                    />
                                </td>
                                <td className="w-25">
                                    <span>value</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey={r._id}>
                                        Group details <i className="far fa-angle-down ml-2"></i>
                                    </Accordion.Toggle>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colSpan="4">
                                    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={r._id}>
                                        <SubTableResults
                                            child={r}
                                            nameRole={r.value}
                                        />
                                    </Accordion.Collapse>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </tbody>)
                else if(r.count!== 0)
                     return(<tbody key={r._id}>
                     <tr>
                    <td><p><b>{r.count}</b> {r.value}</p></td>
                    <td>
                        <DropdownMultiselectParent
                            options={r.parentTech}
                            idRole={r._id}
                            counter = {r.count}
                            nameControl = {r.value}
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td className="w-25">
                        <span>value</span>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                 <tr><td colSpan="4"></td></tr>
                     </tbody>)
                    return (<tbody key={r.value} className="d-none"><tr><td colSpan="4"></td></tr></tbody>)
                })
            }
            
        </table>
        </Accordion>
    );
}

export default LandingResults;
```

component parent

```
function SubTableResults(props) {

    return (
        <table className="table my-2">
            <tbody>
            {
                props.child.talents.map((x,index)=>
                    <tr key={x._id}>
                        <td className="w-25">
                            <ul className="d-table mb-0">
                                <li className="d-table-cell">
                                    <i className="fad fa-user-circle fa-2x"></i>
                                </li>
                                <li className="d-table-cell">
                                    <p>{props.nameRole}</p>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                        <td className="w-25">
                            {
                                x.technology.map(y=>
                                    <DropdownMultiselectChild key={y._id}
                                                              options={y.options}
                                                              obj={props.child.talents}
                                                              indexControl={index}
                                    />
                                )
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td className="w-25">
                        </td>
                        <td className="text-right">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                )
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}

export default SubTableResults;
```

component child

```
const CustomToggle = React.forwardRef(
    ({ children, onClick, value, setValue}, ref) => {

        const setAll = () =>{
            value.filter(t => t.selected === true? t.selected=false:"");
            setValue(value)
        }

        const tooltip = (
            <Tooltip id="tooltip">
                {value.map(t => (<span key={t._id} className="comma">{t.selected === true ? t.name : ""}</span>))}
            </Tooltip>
        );

        return (
            <div
                className="d-flex w-100"
                ref={ref}
                onClick={e => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    onClick(e);
                }}
            >
                <OverlayTrigger overlay={tooltip} placement="top">
                <span className="mr-auto text-truncate"> {value.map(t => (<span
                    className="comma">{t.selected === true ? t.name : ""}</span>))}{(value.filter((t) => t.selected === true).length) > 0 ? "" : children}</span>
                </OverlayTrigger>

                <ul className="list-inline mb-0 ml-auto d-flex">
                    <li className={(value.filter((t) => t.selected === true).length) > 0 ? 'list-inline-item' : 'd-none'}><a
                        href="#/" className="text-black-50 mr-2" onClick={e => {e.preventDefault(); setAll();}}><i className="far fa-times"></i></a></li>
                    <li className="list-inline-item"><i className="far fa-chevron-down"></i></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        )
    }
);

const SelectMultiple = (props) =>{
    let value = [...props.value];
    const setValue = props.setValue;

    const setItem = (selected, main) =>{

        if(selected === false){
            value[props.index].selected = true;
            console.log(props.indexControl, props.index)
            return setValue(value)
        }else{
            value[props.index].selected = false;
            return setValue(value)
        }
    }

    const validateSelected=()=>{
        return value[props.index].selected
    }

    //props.setSelectMultipleChild(props.index, props.indexControl, props.idRole)

    return (
        <div {...{ className: 'counter' }}>
            <ul className="list-inline mr-auto mb-0">
                <li className="list-inline-item">
                    <a href="#/"
                       className="text-decoration-none text-dark"
                       onClick={e => {e.stopPropagation(); setItem(value[props.index].selected, props.value.main)}}>
                        <i className={validateSelected() === true?"fas fa-check-square fa-lg":"far fa-square fa-lg"}></i>
                        <span className="text-dark text-decoration-none ml-2">{value[props.index].name}</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

function DropdownMultiselectChild(props) {

    const [value, setValue] = useState(props.options)


    return (
        <Dropdown as={ButtonGroup} >
            <Dropdown.Toggle as={CustomToggle}
                             value={value}
                             setValue={setValue}
            >
                Choose...
            </Dropdown.Toggle>
            <Dropdown.Menu>
                {value.map((t,index) =>
                    <Dropdown.ItemText key={t._id}>
                        <SelectMultiple
                            value={value}
                            setValue={setValue}
                            index={index}
                            obj={props.obj}
                            indexControl={props.indexControl}
                        />
                    </Dropdown.ItemText>)}
            </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
    );
}

export default DropdownMultiselectChild;
```

Result some like this

```
|   Value      |   Main                            |   Value   |      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Parent1    |   (2value1, 2value3, 1/2value4)   |   Value   |      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |   Child1     |  (value1, value3)                |   Value   |     |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
 |   Child2     |  (value1, value3, value4)        |   Value   |     |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Parent1    |   (value1, value3)                |   Value   |      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My problem is with child's component's (multi-check) because I need that every child where independent but actually if I check value5 in child1 component the child2 set the same value, and I don't know how can I put every child as unique.

I hope I can make myself understood

Comment: Try to regenerate your problem in codesandbox and highlight you're facing the problem in output. Finally add the link here.